# I am little confused about Binary tree

Tags: tree, binary

Is it a convention that while traversing in a binary tree we move to left and then to right?? Why can't we move from right to left?

Comment: This is entirely by convention. You can also call the two nodes "first" and "second" or "red" and "cold" and do it in any order you want. Mainstream programming languages are traditionally typed with latin alphabet, have strong influence from the English language, and so left to right is at least consistent. Maybe if a culture which writes right-to-left had become dominant in computer science, we would be traversing right-to-left.

Comment: *"Why can't we move from right to left?"*: why you think you can't? No one says you can't.

Answer (score -1):

As Binary Tree has a default behaviour of Sorted Order i.e: Small Number than root node to left and Larger Number to Right. So Due to above-mentioned behaviour traversals conventions are left to right with an assumption that above tree is in sorted order.
Whereas it's just a convention, if you want to traverse right to left then you can place Larger Number than Root Node to Left Side and Smaller Number to Right Side of Binary-Tree.

[Binary Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsXIr.png)

Comment: This completely misses the question. A binary search tree is a kind of a binary tree, but not every binary tree is a binary search tree. Also, B-tree is **not** a shorthand for "binary tree". No need to confuse things like that.

Comment: _Thanks for clearing thing about Binary Tree and BST, whereas I think it's just convention and I will edit my answer prior to exact answer about Binary Tree itself_